# How to revert compiled Python 2.6.4 to system default on Snow Leopard?

Tags: python, osx-snow-leopard

So earlier this year I manually built 2.6.4 for Snow Leopard because I wanted a slightly more updated version of Python than what Apple released. This has caused all kinds of problems when installing some eggs like PIL and running other 3rd party python apps. Now I just want to revert everything back to what Snow Leopard ships with because I have to get work done and it's getting in the way. If worse comes to worse, I'm going to reinstall the OS but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You added an extra python somewhere and did not remove/overwrite the vendor version, right?

Comment: Next time you install python, use "make altinstall", it will allow you to type python2.6 and python will be left untouched.

Comment: @Thilo I'm not sure. In /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions I have 2.6 and a symlink to 2.6. When I 'which python' it points to this path. The python version is 2.6.4. What's confusing is that Snow Leopard is supposed to have 2.5.4 and 2.6.1 and none of those are on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `PATH` environment variable so that /usr/bin is ahead of wherever you put your custom compiled Python binary.

Comment: Completely forgot about this. I looked in my .bash_profile and found where I had set the overriding PATH var and commented it out. Now I'm back to 2.6.1. Thanks!